# Lasso tidymodels error: 'x' and 'y' must have same types and lengths

Tags: r, grid, lasso-regression, tidymodels

## Goal

Create a lasso model with a grid search in tidymodels.

Use similar/identical code to the working one by [Julia Silge](https://juliasilge.com/blog/lasso-the-office/) with another data set containing numeric and factor variables.

## Issues

#### Error message (resolved, see edit)

`x` and `y` must have same types and lengths

#### No valid results with LASSO

Standard deviation is Null in all bootstrap cases.

## Code

```
# Data
## Optionally only numeric
data = data[sapply(data, is.numeric)]

# Workflow setup
## Recipe
rec = recipe(PD ~ ., data = data) %>%
   step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
   step_normalize(all_numeric())

## Preparation of the recipe
prep = rec %>% prep()

## Workflow
wf = workflow() %>% add_recipe(rec)


# Lambda grid
lambdas = grid_regular(
   penalty(), 
   levels = 20)

# Bootstrap data
boot = bootstraps(data, times = 5)

# Model
mod = linear_reg(
   penalty = tune(), 
   mixture = 1 # for lasso
) %>% set_engine('glmnet')

# Processing
lasso = tune_grid(
   wf %>% add_model(model), 
   resamples = boot, 
   grid = lambdas)
```

## Error trace back

1. tune_grid(wf %>% add_model(model), 
   resamples = boot, grid = lambdas)
2. tune_grid.workflow(wf %>% add_model(model), 
   resamples = boot, grid = lambdas)
3. tune_grid_workflow(object, resamples = resamples,
   grid = grid, metrics = metrics, pset = param_info, 
   control = control)
4. rlang::eval_tidy(code_path)
5. tune_mod_with_recipe(resamples, grid, object, 
   metrics, control)
6. pull_metrics(resamples, results, control)
7. pulley(resamples, res, ".metrics")
8. full_join(resamples, pulled_vals, by = id_cols)
9. full_join.tbl_df(resamples, pulled_vals, 
   by = id_cols)
10. `names<-`(`*tmp*`, value = vars$alias)
11. `names<-.rset`(`*tmp*`, value = vars$alias)
12. rset_reconstruct(out, x)
13. rset_reconstructable(x, to)
14. col_equals_splits(to_names)
15. vec_equal(x, "splits")

## Notes

When one specific lambda is supplied and the data is fit no error occurs.

If the lambdas supplied by the grid don't result in proper fits, how can the grid be changed?

Only working with numeric predictor variable results in the same error.

## Edit

- Error message, `x` and `y` must have same types and lengths, could be avoided. Initially, dplyr and rsample versions 0.8.5 and 0.0.7 were used. Downgrading rsample to 0.0.6 or upgrading dplyr to 1.0.0 resolved the issue (credits to Max Kuhn).
- LASSO still fails to find appropriate fits.

```r
# Package imports ------
library(readr)
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ──────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.0 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.5.6      ✓ recipes   0.1.12
#> ✓ dials     0.0.6      ✓ rsample   0.0.7 
#> ✓ dplyr     1.0.0      ✓ tibble    3.0.1 
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.1      ✓ tune      0.1.0 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.1      ✓ workflows 0.1.1 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.1      ✓ yardstick 0.0.6 
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ─────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard()  masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()   masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()      masks stats::lag()
#> x ggplot2::margin() masks dials::margin()
#> x yardstick::spec() masks readr::spec()
#> x recipes::step()   masks stats::step()
library(reprex)

# Data ------
# Prepared according to the Blog post by Julia Silge
# https://juliasilge.com/blog/lasso-the-office/
urlfile = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shudras/office_data/master/office_data.csv'
office = read_csv(url(urlfile))[-1]
#> Warning: Missing column names filled in: 'X1' [1]
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   .default = col_double()
#> )
#> See spec(...) for full column specifications.

#office_split = initial_split(office, strata = season)
#office_train = training(office_split)
#office_test = testing(office_split)

# Lasso modeling -------
## Recipe and train it 
office_rec <- recipe(imdb_rating ~ ., data = office) %>%
  #
  step_zv(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  prep(strings_as_factors = FALSE) # Training

## Create workflow 
wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(office_rec)

## Parameter tuning 
set.seed(4653)
### Bootstrapping data for resampling
office_boot <- bootstraps(office, times = 5, strata = season)

### Create lambda seach gird
lambda_grid <- grid_regular(penalty(), levels = 20)

### The model
tune_spec <- linear_reg(penalty = tune(), mixture = 1) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")

### Apply the workflow
lasso_grid <- tune_grid(
  wf %>% add_model(tune_spec),
  resamples = office_boot,
  grid = lambda_grid
)
#> ! Bootstrap1: internal: Standardabweichung ist Null
#> ! Bootstrap2: internal: Standardabweichung ist Null
#> ! Bootstrap3: internal: Standardabweichung ist Null
#> ! Bootstrap4: internal: Standardabweichung ist Null
#> ! Bootstrap5: internal: Standardabweichung ist Null
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Can you create a [small reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with data so that we can understand what it is that is causing your problem?

Comment: I created a reprex (edit). The initial error was resolved by changing dplyr or rsample versions. LASSO does still not find valid results, i.e. Bootstrap5: internal: standard deviation is Null.

Comment: Getting the same error message just trying to run the examples in `last_fit`. I just upgraded tidyverse so seems like a versioning thing.